# Taxonomy overview search term

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

In this manager:

admin/structure/taxonomy

admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/[fruit]/overview

There is a way to add a search a term?

So, if you have 100 terms it will easier to find a term.

This one is not ported at all https://www.drupal.org/project/term_search

This module is not full ported to D8
https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager

I also find this interested article to alter a task in a specific vocabulary. https://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/replacing-vocabulary-listing I created the view, but I still find out how to add a tab for that view in the overview taxonomy.

There other way to add an option to search a term in manager?

Answer (score 0):

Views with exposed filters sound like a great way to add a Search page to Vocabulary configuration tabs.

You can add your Views page to Vocabulary pages through Views configuration. Since the List already exists as the default tab, simply configure your Views page `Menu` option as a normal `Menu tab` and set the page path to the `[path-to-default-vocabulary-page]/search`.

The tab will appear as one of the tabs you see when you visit the Vocabulary configuration page.

Comment: I'll test that  today

Comment: I tried It works have way. It is displayed the Search tab. But view is getting an error. The view works alone.. but the I add path to admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/category/overview/search and Menu Tab "Some mandatory parameters are missing (&quot;taxonomy_vocabulary&quot;) "

Comment: Have you added the Contextual filter for the vocabulary? You should have /%/ instead of the /category/ in the path. The contextual filter should take the `Raw value from URL` under `Provide default value`, and `Path component` 5. That way you get search pages on all vocabularies. There also seems to be a bug that needs to be patched so Tabs can work: [Views does not create parent local task for a default local task](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2804195), or create the parent item menu item manually.