# Replace taxonomy vocubulary administration page with a view

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I would like to replace *admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/my_vocabulary/overview* with a custom view.
 Some of my vocabularies have custom fields that I would like to display and use as filter for the view.
For *admin/people* a view exists that can simply be modified.
Is it possible to create such a view also for *admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/my_vocabulary/overview* ?

Comment: The *admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/my_vocabulary/overview* is en entity overview page not a view see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Vocabulary.php/class/Vocabulary/8.2.x

Comment: See also: [Taxonomy overview search term](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/270715/taxonomy-overview-search-term)